# Google Earth KML with polygones with longitudes greater than 180deg?

Tags: kml, latitude-longitude, google-earth

I use polygones in kml files for displaying a rocket's flightpath from ground into orbit in google earth kml files.

the problem is, that google earth can't handle longitued greater than 180deg, so when a rocket will circle more than ones around the globe the longitued values has to be recalculated.
Is there a way in using longitudes like 720deg and google can translate this by itself? I would prefer this, because I don'thave to change my programme and you can directly see the revolutions of the rocket around earth by its coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KML definition indeed only allows arguments

- between -180 and 180 for longitude
- between -90 and 90 for latitude

see [KML Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html) - element "coordinates"

So I am afraid you will need to normalize your lon by introducing an angle function.

Comment: hi,

okay, it's their specification, but it's strange to have this limitation on a globe.
never the less, thank you! :) (+1)

Comment: I wonder if you came up with a transformation of longitudes outside [-180,180]. Somehow tricky ... I played around with it a bit and created this one (Excel - argument is in B3 - no angle funcs needed) ...   =IF(MOD(INT(B3/180);2)=0;MOD(B3;180);MOD(B3;360)-360)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by MikeD you will need to normalize to fit in the specs. Here is a [site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) from Chris Veness with spherical formulas for doing lots of calculations that otherwise boggle the mind.